# Are there any encrypted file systems available for Solaris 10?

Tags: encryption, zfs, solaris-10

**BACKGROUND:**
We are running Unidata 7.2-5 on Solaris 10 for our data warehouse.  There is no database encryption option that works well with our applications.  We were looking at ZFS, but it seems that ZFS will only be available under OpenSolaris.

Any other suggestions for some type of EFS under Solaris 10?

Comment: I thought ZFS was an integral part of "Real" Solaris, as well as being available in OpenSolaris.  
I suspect you could probably use dm-crypt somehow, but then you've got more overhead.

Comment: Yes, ZFS is available, but it looks like the encryption pieces are not going to get back ported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cryptographic_file_systems
ZFS filesystem encryption is due for integration in Q1 2010.

OpenSolaris gets all the *new* stuff for ZFS earlier then Solaris 10 (think Fedora and RHEL).

After a quick google search I found this (not really suited for production):
http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=1029
and
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5074517

Popular UFS or VxFS do not have any encryption support.

Comment: Yes, ZFS is available for OpenSolaris but it looks like the encryption pieces are not going to get back ported to Solaris 10.  That is the reason why I'm looking again